# SQL Query related to maximum job period

Tags: sql

I am having a table with four columns namely, eid,ename,hire_date and end_date. Now I want to write a query displaying the name and id of the employee who has worked for the maximum days and the no. of days for which he/she has worked. I have tried a lot but unfortunately I am not getting the desired answer.

Comment: What database do you use? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you been able to calculate the number of days everyone has worked as a stepping stone to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hth..

```
CREATE TABLE tests 
(eid int,ename VARCHAR(20),hire_date DATETIME , end_date Datetime)

INSERT INTO dbo.tests
    ( eid ,
      ename ,
      hire_date ,
      end_date
    )
VALUES  ( 1 , -- eid - int
      'A1' , -- ename - varchar(20)
      '2015-01-03 10:41:43' , -- hire_date - datetime
      '2015-03-03 10:41:43'  -- end_date - datetime
    ),
    ( 2 , -- eid - int
      'A2' , -- ename - varchar(20)
      '2015-05-03 10:41:43' , -- hire_date - datetime
      '2015-06-03 10:41:43'  -- end_date - datetime
    )

    SELECT TOP 1 eid,ename,DATEDIFF(DAY,hire_date,end_date) AS DaysWORKED         FROM tests ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY,hire_date,end_date) desc
```

Thanks